# enviar variable escrita en de código Google apps script a JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, google-apps-script-html-service

Estoy haciendo una especie de página web que hace un raspado de otra web, donde obtengo y guardo datos en una variable del tipo "var", dicha variable quiero enviarla a un archivo JavaScript que tengo dentro de Google apps script del tipo "javascript.html".

¿Cómo puedo enviar la variable del archivo del tipo ".gs" al archivo "javascript.html"?

El archivo JavaScript lo abro así en mi HTML

```
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">    
    <?!= HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile("css").getContent(); ?>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1> Hola. </h1>
    <?!= HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile("javaScript").getContent(); ?>    
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: En lugar de usar `HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile` podrías usar `HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile` con su respectiva asignación de variable y comando `evaluate`. Si requires mayor detalle agrega un [mcve] (incluye tanto el código del archivo gs como el del archivo html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

cargas el código html como plantilla para poder ejecutar funciones del lado del servidor desde tu plantilla html de esta manera donde el archivo html se llama "web.html"

```
 function doGet() {
  return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("web").evaluate()
}
```

para obtener una variable del lado del servidor del tipo apps script ".gs" y obtenerla en JavaScript puedes usar un botón donde envías el contenido de dicha variable. Un ejemplo de código .gs seria este:

```
    function doGet() {//carga la página web 
      return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("web").evaluate();
    }
    
    function include(elemento) {//carga javaScript y css o cualquier elemento externo
      return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile(elemento).getContent();
    }

var pi=3,1415;//variable que quiero obtener en javaScript
```

el codigo html seria este:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">    
   <?!=include('javaScript');?>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1> pulsa el boton para obtener en javaScript la variable pi</h1>
        <input type="button" value="Click me" onclick="obtenerPi(<?= pi ?>)">
  </body>
</html>
```

por ultimo el archivo javaScript sería así:

```
 <script>
function obtenerPi(pi) {
    console.log(pi);
}
</script>
```

así obtienes la variable pi en javaScript

también se puede insertando en javascript la siguiente clase donde la funcion que quieres ejecutar lo sustituyes por tu función de código .gs

```
google.script.rum."función que quiero ejecutar"
```